# How to generate more characters?

Tags: python

I'm making a code generator based on the popular game Among US, which has 4-letter game codes.
I built this program to generate one for you, to see if it actually exists, but instead of four letters, only one gets generated four times.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

```
import random
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
quantity = int(input('How many codes do you want? '))

def create_code():
     for c in range(4):
         code = ''
         code += random.choice(chars)

         return code

for i in range(0, quantity):
    print('Your code is', create_code())
```

Comment: You reset `code` in each `for ` loop.

Comment: There are 2 issues, one return is inside loop and then you reset the value of code inside the loop, please see my solution

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way, which uses `.choices()` (plural)

```
import random
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
list_of_chars = random.choices(chars, k=4)
print(''.join(list_of_chars))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import random
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
quantity = int(input('How many codes do you want? '))

def create_code():
    code = ''
    for c in range(4):
        code += random.choice(chars)
    return code

for i in range(0, quantity):
    print('Your code is', create_code())
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the variable `code` within your loop so it's reset every time. It should be:

```py
import random
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
quantity = int(input('How many codes do you want? '))

def create_code():
    code = ''
    for c in range(4):
        code += random.choice(chars)
    return code

for i in range(0, quantity):
    print('Your code is', create_code())
```

Answer (score -1):

A few problems. You are overwriting the `code` variable each time through the loop with `code = ''`. You are also returning from within the loop. Try this:

```
def create_code():
    code = ''
    for c in range(4):
        code += random.choice(chars)
    return code
```